# pydev to postgres issue with code

Tags: python, eclipse, postgresql, pydev

I am trying to send data from python using pydev to postgresql. I am finding more than one error and could really need help. Many thanks! One of the error says:

> psycopg2.InterfaceError: cursor already closed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code to create the table

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import sys
import csv
from itertools import count
path = r'C:\Users\sammy\Downloads\E0.csv'
with open(path, "r") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    firstline = 1
    con = None
    con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='football' user='postgres' password='XXX'")   
    cur = con.cursor()
    con.commit()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE testtest1234")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE testtest1234 (HY INTEGER)")
    for row in readCSV:
        if firstline:
            firstline=0
            continue 
        new_data = row[19]
        try:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO testtest1234 values ("+new_data+")")
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM testtest1234;")
        except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
            if con:
                con.rollback() 
            print ("Error %s % e", e)
            sys.exit(1) 
        finally:   
            if con:
                con.close()
            print (new_data)

print(" ".join(row))
out=open("new_data.csv", "w")
output = csv.writer(out)

for row in new_data:
    output.writerow(row)

out.close()
```

Here is my code to insert in the table

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import sys
import csv
from itertools import count
path = r'C:\Users\sammy\Downloads\E0.csv'
with open(path, "r") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    con = None
    con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='football' user='postgres' password='XXX'")   
    cur = con.cursor()
    con.commit()
    for row in readCSV:
        new_data = row[19]
        print (new_data)


try:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO testtest1234 values ("+new_data+")")

except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
    if con:
        con.rollback() 
    print ("Error %s % e", e)
    sys.exit(1) 
finally:   
    if con:
        con.close()

print(" ".join(row))
out=open("new_data.csv", "w")
output = csv.writer(out)

for row in new_data:
    output.writerow(row)

    out.close()
```

Comment: did you debug what line generate that error? And what other error you got?

Comment: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sammy\eclipse-workspace\football123\cnttestreal.py", line 24, in <module>
0
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO testtest1234 values ("+new_data+")")
psycopg2.InterfaceError: cursor already closed

Comment: I have the same problem. when the application makes multiple requests. but when it's only one it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the connection inside the loop, so only the first one row is inserted.

```
for row in readCSV:
    try:
         ...
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
         ...
    finally:   
        if con:
            con.close()
```

Comment: Could you please type it all?

Comment: I showing you the problem. `con.close`  inside the loop. Just move it outside the `for row` loop

Comment: I moved the for in the try statement. When printing the data I only get "0" and nothing on the db..

Comment: Well but now you dont have the `cursor already closed` error?

Comment: Well now you have to debug further. For example instead of `execute('stringQuery')`  you create a variable `@query = 'stringQuery'` so you can know the value before execute. Also why you `INSERT` and then do a `SELECT`??

Comment: It worked. Turned out the con.commit() had to be moved forward down the code!